# What are the modifiable char array types in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, char, stack

I am trying to synthesize my knowledge in char arrays but I feel I am missing something. I can only think of these three scenarios (when it comes to stack, I am not talking about doing `const int SIZE = 6; char *word = new char[SIZE];` )

**case 1 :** not permissible

```
char *word = "message"; 
word[0] = 'M';
```

**case 2 :** permissible

```
const int SIZE = 8;
char word[SIZE] = "message"; 
word[0] = 'M';
```

**case 3 :** permissible

```
char word[] = "message"; 
word[0] = 'M';
```

Are there any others ways to create a char array in c++? If so what modifications are permissible?

Comment: You forgot about `std::array`.

Comment: Note that `char *word = "message";` is *illegal* in C++11 and later and should not even compile (if it does, then your compiler has a non-standard extension to allow that). A string literal is read-only data, so you MUST (and should) use a pointer to `const` data, eg: `const char *word = "message";` instead.

Comment: `const auto word = ...;` is what you likely want.

Answer (score 2):

If you declare the array with const type, you aren't allowed to modify it. If you declare it with non-const type, you are allowed to modify it. That's the main rule that you need to remember.

The rules of the language prevent you from accidentally breaking this rule using a pointer variable, as well. If you have a `char*`, you're allowed to use it to modify the array it points to. If you have a `const char*`, you're not. In the case of a non-modifiable array such as a string literal, the compiler should not allow you to assign its address to a `char*`. If the compiler allows Case 1 to compile, you should configure it with appropriate flags so that it does not.

In short, the modifiable array types are the non-`const` ones, and you can obtain a non-`const` pointer only to such an array, therefore such pointers can also be used for modification. (That is, unless you do something unsafe, like using `const_cast`).

Comment: I know that case 1 doesn't work that's why I wrote "not permissible" next to it. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: @CSstudZ what's your question then?

Comment: I updated the answer, hopefully this answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

> Are there any others ways to create a char array in c++? If so what modifications are permissible?

Syntactically yes there are

Non Modifiable:

```
auto word1 = "abc";
const auto word2 = "abc";
constexpr auto word3 = "abc";
constexpr char word4 = "abc";
auto word5{"abc"};
const auto word6{"abc"};
```

Modifiable

```
char word7[]{"abc"};
```